# Integration $\sqrt{1+x^{-1}}$ using subtitutions

Tags: integration

Integrate

$$\int \sqrt{1+x^{-1}}dx$$
When I began to solve, I used the tangent inverse function.  I tried substituting u for $\sqrt{x}$, but I stopped somewhere and I couldn't move further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Substituting $$t^2=1+\frac{1}{x}$$ then we get $$x=\frac{1}{t^2-1}$$ and $$dx=-2\,{\frac {t}{ \left( {t}^{2}-1 \right) ^{2}}}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=\sinh^2 u$,

$$I = \int \sqrt{ 1+ x^{-1} } dx$$
$$= \int \frac{\cosh u}{\sinh u} 2\sinh u \cosh u du $$

$$= \int 2\cosh^2 u du= \int (1+ \cosh 2u)du $$
$$= u + \frac 12 \sinh 2u + C$$